# Not able to find 'APIS & AUTH' or 'PUSH' under Domain Verification

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api, webhooks

I'm trying to setup a webhook (https://app.example.com/notications) for Push Notifications coming from Google Drive API version 3.

After having set-up everything I'm getting error:

```
...
errors": [
    {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
        "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://app.example.com"
    }
],
...
```

There are a couple of results on google (most of which are here on SE) that talk about this issue. 
One of them suggested below steps to follow:

1. Go to the Google Developers Console.
2. Choose or create a project.
3. In the sidebar on the left, click APIs & auth, then click Push.
4. Click  Add domains.
5. Fill in the form, then again click Add domains.

but I am not able to find 'APIS & AUTH' or 'PUSH' under Domain Verification option in my project. Please let me know where it would be or what would be the reason?

Quick help would really be appreciated!!

Thanks,

Comment: Are you referring to this [picture](http://imgur.com/9OfiQIn) under the Domain Verification tab